# Pytest/Allure - How to generate testcase description?

Tags: python, pytest, allure, adaptor

I'm still fairly new to Allure, and I'm trying to generate a test description in my reports. Looking at other SO questions and pytest-allure-adaptor documentation, there doesn't seem to be an option to do this.

The closest I've gotten was writing this:

```py
def test_one():
   """
   This is the test description.
   """
   assert pass
```

And that's very limited, since it automatically collapses it. In the Allure example report, you can see that they can use headers and probably markdown of some sort. How do I do that with pytest-allure-adaptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't change the type of description in PyTest Adaptor. See the issue https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/93

Comment: Yes thank you, I made the issue after I didn't get an answer here :)

Comment: Update: for those interested, this feature has been implemented.