# Allure with Pytest: no decorators for Title and Description

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I did try to use these decorators in a test, but the compiler has issues because the decorators for both the Title and Description are not recognized.

I did use

```
@allure.feature("feature1")
@allure.story("story1")
```

Without issues, but

```
@allure.description("test")
@allure.title("The test title")
```

does not exist. Is this a limitation of the python port of the allure tool? The documentation does not mention that there is neither a description nor a title decorator, but the Allure page shows that these are in fact legit commands that you can use for Allure.

My assumption was that the porting of Allure for Python would include everything; but I start to think that probably it has only the basics, like the story, step and such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pytest/Allure - How to generate testcase description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260895/pytest-allure-how-to-generate-testcase-description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author of `allure-python` here.

You are right, there are no such decorators as `description` or `title`.
The reason is `allure-python` collects test title and description from the `pytest`'s native means -- for bare python tests the are collected from test function title and docstring respectively.

Overally, `allure-python` is not a 1-to-1 port of Java version of allure but instead an adaptor to convert `pytest`'s own structures and means for allure report generation. Historically, only those parts of allure that are missing from native pytest (like steps) are implemented explicitly.

However, if you would feel more comfortable with those decorators feel free to open a pull request to add their implementation.

Best, Ivan.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I am OK if they are not there; since I can assign names and descriptions as you mentioned, using pytest. 
Allure is a nice framework;I just find a bit hard to adapt tutorials made for JS, into something that works on Python, but it is understandable, considering that most of the work done with web is actually done via JS, not much with python :)

Comment: Hey, is it possibly to set the test name by a parameter? That is given from parameterized?